# How to disable certain days in custom date picker

Tags: android, material-design, custom-datetimepicker

How to disable certain dates in android date picker . for example : I wants to disable next 2 days from today and then range is upto 10 days .Like suppose today is 09-04-2019 then I wants to disable 10th April ,11th April and enable days ranging from 12th April to next 15 Days . Is there any library available?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and since the android one is too basic you might want to use some library to achieve this. I used [this](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#additional-options) library for this purpose.

You have to use this line:

```
dp.setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)
```

You have to pass array of Calendar as an parameter which contains all the selectable dates.